# how to create insert query in excel?

Tags: excel

I want to create insert query in excel for a table which has 3 columns,2 are availble to me and 3rd one I need to create from the 1st column with prefix 'REV' and last 3 character of 1st columns string.

Lets say I have below two columns in A1 and B1 cells of my worksheet:

```
CHBMOB 'Test Code'
```

I want my insert as below

```
insert into my_tab values ('CHBMOB','Test Code','REVMOB');
```

I tried using below

```
="insert into my_tab values ('"&A1&"','"&B1"',concat('REV',right(A1,3));"
```

But it did not work for 3rd column,please help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close. Instead:

```
="insert into my_tab values ('" & A1 & "','" & B1 & "',concat('REV', '" & right(A1,3) & "');"
```

I suspect the following would also work fine for you and may quicker at the database since you don't have to waste cpu cycles doing the `concat`:

```
="insert into my_tab values ('" & A1 & "','" & B1 & "','REV" & right(A1,3) & "');"
```

Comment: Don't you need another & between B1 and the next double quote?